# Remove hash with php

Tags: php

How can I remove #id=756 with php?

`?_otherstuff_#id=756'`

I've tried with `substr()` but it did not worked correctly.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: remove it from a string?

Comment: You need to provide a bit more information here - what are you trying to use the string for and how are you obtaining it.

Comment: Sure, the question is how can I remove the hash, not just $id=756,
I need the string without the hash.

Comment: Just the question I had, I up voted you.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve it with **substr** as well.

Here you go With `substr`:

```
$a = '?_otherstuff_#id=756';
$var = substr($a, 0, strpos($a, "#"));
```

Comment: This methodology is redundant and has unnecessary overhead. It's also not `substr()`'s function to do these kind of actions. I'm stumped :P

Answer (score 2):

```
$my_string = str_replace('#id=756', '', $my_string);
```

Or use regular expression to match each ID;

```
$my_string = preg_replace('/\#id=\d+/', '', $my_string);
```

Or to only remove the hash, and only on that place (so it won't accidentally match other hashes floating around in your URL);

```
$my_string = preg_replace('/_otherstuff_#/', '_otherstuff_', $my_string)
```

And here is one with omega-overkill, but to show the possibilities:

```
$counter = 0;

$my_string = '?_otherstuff_#id=756&_otherstuff_#id=912';

$my_string = preg_replace_callback('/_otherstuff_#/', function($matches) {
    $GLOBALS['counter']++;

    echo ($matches[0]).' (repacement nr. '.$GLOBALS['counter'].')<br />';

    return '_otherstuff_';
}, $my_string);

echo '<br />'.$my_string;
```

**Output**

```
_otherstuff_# (repacement nr. 1)
_otherstuff_# (repacement nr. 2)

?_otherstuff_id=756&_otherstuff_id=912
```

Comment: T+he question is how can I remove the hash, not just $id=756

Comment: Your question is way too vague, or you fail to grasp the idea ;). Maybe like this? `$my_string = preg_replace('/_otherstuff_#/', '_otherstuff_', $my_string)`

Answer (score 2):

you can use [parse_url](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)   that can split url to

```
scheme - e.g. http
host
port
user
pass
path
query - after the question mark ?
fragment - after the hashmark #
```

after remove fragment  can build url by `http_build_url` https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-url.php

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove hash as per your question title

```
$str =  "?_otherstuff_#id=756'";

$newstr = str_replace("#","", $str);
```